# WebApi using EF, Windows Authentication failed

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have built a RESTful web service using WebApi. I'm using Entity Framework to connect to the database. Localy works ok. When I upload the site to a host provider and make a request, I get back a 401 result, along with the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin
Date: Thu, 20 Jun 2013 11:28:47 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

The first strange thing is that if instead of EF I use the classic `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` it works fine.
The second strange this is that if I run the project local and in connection string I connect to the remote server, it also works!

A though just came to me. Could it be that my connection string is like this, using `System.Data.SqlClient` as provider?

```
<add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDB;User Id=user;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I tried some of the suggestions in this SO question, but nothing worked.
[Disable Windows Authentication for WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588397/disable-windows-authentication-for-webapi)

Any suggestions please? I've been strugling with this 3 days now, implemented HttpModules, custom Attributes, reading about handlers. I'm really overwhelmed now.

Comment: I doubt it has something to do with EF. Enable logging in IIS and see a detailed error message for this request.

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly the case of Windows Authentication kicking in, as you see from the WWW-Authenticate headers.

```
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
```

You must disable Windows authentication. If you can use IIS manager, ensure authentication settings are like this.

[image]

Or you can use web.config (assuming IIS 7 integrated).

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <authentication>
      <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
      <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
      <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
    </authentication>
  </security>
  ...
<system.webServer>
```

Comment: Assuming OP didn't make a mistake while testing, how does changing from EF to a simple `SqlCommand` result in different behaviour?

Comment: It cannot. I really doubt changing SqlCommand to EF is anything to do with 401. It is obvious IIS is sending those headers back.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the IIS configuration. The thing with EF and 'SqlCommand' was checked many times, but again I'm on the project many days and many hours and I might just be tired. I'll check the configuration thing when I have some time.