# ASP.NET Web API Override authorization filter for a handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization, asp.net-web-api2, authorize-attribute

How can I disable an authorization filter for a specific GET handler in Web API?

There's a custom authorization filter on the class level but for one of the methods I need to have no security.  I tried applying `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute but it still runs through the higher-level filter and fails. That custom filter derives from `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`. The class also have two another attributes: `OverrideAuthentication` and `EnableCors`.

I tried `AllowAnonymous` attribute but it doesn't.

Sample code:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
[OverrideAuthentication]
[AccountAuthorization]
public class AccountsController : ApiController
{

    [Route("api/accounts/{accountNumber}/GetX")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetX(string accountNumber)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        IEnumerable<string> apiKey;
        if (!Request.Headers.TryGetValues("X-ApiKey", out apiKey) || apiKey.Count() != 1 || apiKey.First() != API_KEY)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }

        // Process
        // ..
        // ..

        return response;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** The linked answer doesn't explain what's the solution.

Comment: What if you remove `[OverrideAuthentication]` and `[AccountAuthorization]` from the controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AllowAnonymous not working with Custom AuthorizationAttribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595723/allowanonymous-not-working-with-custom-authorizationattribute)

Comment: See this too, you may be able to allow anonymous on specific URLs in the web api.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588397/disable-windows-authentication-for-webapi

Comment: @MaxSorin: Still doesn't works.

Comment: Then you are intercepting the request elsewhere that is not visible to us.

Comment: @MaxSorin: It works if I remove both the `[OverrideAuthentication]` and [`AccountAuthorization]` attribute but not if I remove `[OverrideAuthentication]` only. Btw, did you edit your comment later cause I read it as only `[OverrideAuthentication]` :)

Comment: @SteveCzetty: I looked into that answer but I don't understand what's the solution? The function looks for the `AllowAnonmousAttribute` on the action descriptor and the controller descriptor to decide whether to skip authorization or not. I have the attribute on the action but it still isn't skipped and goes through the custom authorization filter & fails. The accepted answer doesn't explain anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out at last.

Since there is already an existing custom authorization filter on the class/controller level, therefore, to override a specific action handler (the method) and have it work without any authorization filters, we need to override the filter at the controller/class level. So adding the `OverrideAuthorization` filter did the trick. Now `AllowAnonymous` will be to do its magic.

```
[Route("api/accounts/{accountNumber}/GetX")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[OverrideAuthorization]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetX(string accountNumber)
{
    // Process     
    // ..
    // ..
}
```