# SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ee7, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ee7

Tags: xmlhttprequest, microsoft-edge, error-code

I got this error in Microsoft Edge. What does it mean? Searching online mostly gives me threads about people encountering the error in products.

Answer (score 3):

If the hostname that is targeted by the XMLHttpRequest call (`www.mysite.something`) can't be resolved on the machine doing the call, then error 00002ee7 will be reported.

Try doing **`nslookup www.mysite.something`** in a CMD prompt to check if that is indeed the case. If so, either fix the hostname to what it should be, or add an entry to the `hosts`-file of the machine, or get in touch with an Admin so they can make the DNS resolve the hostname.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out the webpage was loaded from cache and attempted to reach the server. This opaque error apparently means "check your internet connection".

Answer (score 2):

I received this error when trying to load a local webpage; there was a typo in a ternary statement.

```
 var foo = (typo) ? 6 : 3;
```

The page loaded just fine in Chrome & Firefox (with a value of 3), but the page would not load in Edge and I got this same cryptic error.

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ee7, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ee7

Fixing the typo resolved the error message.

Comment: That's weird. Thanks for sharing, hopefully it'll help others!

Answer (score 2):

We had this problem in an installation of our product at a customer site. That customer was known to have a lot of lock downs and restrictions on their servers.

First, we had two separate sites in our product: one front end site and one back end site serving up date through a WebAPI. We never got that working in this customer environment.

Then, we no longer hosted the WebAPI separately, but hosted it/included it on a virtual path "/api/" inside the main site. But for this customer installation we would see all XMLHttpRequests go immediately to "(Aborted)" with the above mentioned error when the requests went from "http://mainsite.corporation.local/" to "http://mainsite.corporation.local/api/some/stuff".

We already had set up the authentication for the "/api/" path to not inherit  Windows Authentication from the main site, using the tips on [Disable Windows Authentication for WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588397/disable-windows-authentication-for-webapi/20409478#20409478)

What finally worked was then to use relative URLs: have the main site set off its XMLHttpRequests to "/api/Various/Stuff" and "/api/More/Stuff" and everything worked just fine!

What was different in our situation that that of the original post: the browser was Internet Explorer 11, but Edge, but the problem and error code was the same. The error situation also occurred in Chrome.