# How to call Windows Authenticated API using HTTP Client

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I want to call windows authenticated API using HTTP client. I tried with below approaches

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() 
                      {
                          UseDefaultCredentials = true
                      }); 

var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() 
                      {
                          Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
                      });
```

Both are not working.

Is there any alternative using HTTP Client

Comment: Can you have a try as follows:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588397/disable-windows-authentication-for-webapi/20409478

Comment: I tried that approach it didn't work and I am calling API from WPF application